# Paypal AutoRecharge

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, paypal, payment

I want to implement a system where if my customers balance in the website goes less than 10 it need to automatically recharged with pay pal. I had a look at paypal recurring. that was not exactly I was looking for. [Automatically charge PayPal account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398641/automatically-charge-paypal) here you see the previous question related question. but that is not exactly meeting my requirement.

if I implement payal express check out does it work like **auto recharge**. because I have not found a related information

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reference Transactions with Express Checkout, in which case you would send the transaction ID from a previous transaction along with the new amount you'd like to charge in [DoReferenceTransaction](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doreferencetransaction-api-operation-nvp).  In order to do this you'll need to get reference transactions approved and enabled on your PayPal account for use with EC.

Alternatively, you could use the [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_adaptivepayments.pdf) platform, which includes [Preapproval](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation) profiles that allow you to charge people at any time using a preapproval key generated at the time they setup your application.  This is covered in depth in Chapter 8 of that Adaptive Payments doc I linked to, and it's also covered in various other places through-out that doc.