# Using API or customer permission, Is it possible to get payment from customer account any time?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

Using API or customer permission, Is it possible to get payment from customer account any time ?

Actually I have one cloth store,

When my custom make payment first time while purchasing something using paypal wallet/account, i will have set of permission from his paypal account,

Using that i need a functionality when that person buy second time, there account will be auto debited, using their saved paypal token

Is Paypal provide this type of any services or API ?

If yes then tell me some more details i.e. how it works and what is require for that i.e token, API key or any other.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Automatically charge PayPal account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398641/automatically-charge-paypal-account/2398943#2398943)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link below for the details to see if this payment method meet your requirement.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/?mark=billing%20agreement